# Check if wifi is enabled and sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-wifi, wifimanager

I've got a little problem.. i have a wifi toggle and i can enable it or disable it. I'm saving the toggle state with sharedpreferences and in the onCreate i wrote this code:

```
sPref  = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // Inizializzo la sharedpreferences
    ToggleButton wifitoggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.wifitoggle); 
    boolean togglewifi = sPref.getBoolean("KEY", false);   
        if (togglewifi || wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) 
        {

            wifitoggle.setChecked(true);
        }
            else
        {
            wifitoggle.setChecked(false);
        }
```

The state is saved and it goes well but as you can see i'm trying to check also if the wifi is enabled or not (For example enable it throught the android wifi settings and not from my application). Right now if i try to enable the wifi throught the settings and i open my application doesn't display that the wifi is enabled.. Something's wrong in the `if` condition? Thanks.

Comment: Use  if (togglewifi && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work in all cases as the user is enabled to change the Wifi state at every time and your application can not recognize this with your code. For example if `togglewifi=true` because you saved the state somewhere earlier then you set your button to checked but that does not mean that the wifi is enabled. The exclusive or will not check the second condition as `TRUE || FALSE = TRUE` and `TRUE || TRUE = TRUE`. The outcome in this case only depends on the first parameter. Fix for your if then else construct:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
ToggleButton wifiToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.wifitoggle);
wifiToggle.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
```

Comment: do you mean something like: `if (togglewifi) 
  {
       
   wifitoggle.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
  }
   else
  {
   wifitoggle.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
  }` ?

Comment: Am I get it right? The toogle states indicates whether wifi is enabled or not. Then you do not need to save the state in the preferences because this state only depends on the current wifi state. So replace the whole block with the snippet above, without an if then else statement.

Comment: But if i enable the wifi in my application the toggle change state from off to on (i change the icon), and if i don't save the state when i exit from app the state resets.. or not?

Comment: No. The WifiManager is an external source and always provides you the current value. So if you change the state in your App then the WifiManager will recognise that as well and again provides you the current value.

Comment: Can you please show me how you would write the code please? i don't understand at all.. Just take my code if you want as example

Comment: Yesssss. you were right! Thank you. it works.. So if i do other toggles like for data or bluetooth for example, the principle it's the same right?

Comment: Yes, as long as there is a system service that provides you access to this information. You can find a list of accessible services [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

Answer (score 0):

Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status

[Check this](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges)

Comment: i need only put `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>` in the manifest?

Comment: @David_D yes and write Broadcast Receiver for That. and update your Shared preferences value.

Comment: writing the same if condition i wrote before?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to check wifi enabled or not :-

```
            boolean wifiEnabled = AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
```

If wifi is enabled check :-

```
// if WIFI Enabled get lat/long using WIFI Services
        if (wifiEnabled) {
            //do something
            Log.d("Network", "Network");
            }
        }
```